# Do hardware design engineers design circuits from scratch?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, design, hardware

I'm new to hardware prototyping and circuit design.  Where do ardware engineers look for reliable circuits that would work for the first time of prototype?

I know this is a general question. I'm looking for advice instead of a specific answer.

Comment: Define "from scratch" and "first time". First time ever for that type of circuit? Or just a first run? "*where do HW engineers look for reliable circuits*" This seems to imply there exists a repository of  circuits somewhere and that you tend to build it without understanding it first (Don't do that.) Where? The answer nowadays is obviously the internet.

Comment: This is per site scope definition not the place to ask for general advise or opinions. Your question is way too broad, you _need_ to ask something more specific on this Q&A site. In general, engineers first write down a technical spec and there's often a BoM budget. Then design accordingly.

Comment: I usually start from the HDK or datasheet of whatever technology or IC we are interested in integrating or designing a board around. They usually have nice **reference schematics** . Sometimes I even choose the IC based on which mfg provides the most complete reference schematics ! (But shhh, don't tell my coworkers ;) )

Comment: I don't expect a circuit I find online to be reliable. Just only enough to tell me how it needs to work to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Most of the better IC manufacturers have reference circuit designs for their devices.  They also offer prototype boards that can be bought or obtained free (if you're a big enough customer).

Comment: One of the essential engineering skills is *laziness* (when applied in the right place). When you can work less and achieve the same result - it is probably the right way to go. If you can find a circuit (or any design - if applied to other fields) which does what you need - take it as is/minimum modification. If you can't - design it from scratch.

Comment: @SteveSh the lower cost version of that is to search ""**IC Here** breakout board" on your favorite electronic marketplace .  There are oodles of inexpensive demo boards for many ICs made by variety of individuals and small companies. It is a good alternate  even if the mfg sells a demo board through normal channels because it is usually hundred or thousands of dollars if you don't have that volume customer relationship.

Comment: @dknguyen, I don't think the OP's implying anything of the sort. I think it's just a perfectly straightforward question. Off-topic, though.

Comment: @TonyM I'm keying in the word "reliable" as in "can build as is and have it work."

Comment: Overall, the answer to the headline question is "Yes" but the good ones only design from scratch the part that absolutely must be specific to your application. This is why user requirements and design specification is so critical, it helps identify those critical parts that require additional attention - lest you disappoint your customer! To @EugeneSh point steal/copy the rest with reckless abandon and you will find good work as a hardware designer . As a complete subjective aside, in my experience very few product designers want a hardware designer that reinvents everything just because.

Comment: @DKNguyen, no idea about any of that. I commented on It was this statement instead: *This seems to imply there exists a repository of circuits somewhere and that you tend to build it without understanding it first (Don't do that.)* OP's not implying that...don't know where that deduction could come from.

Comment: @TonyM Oh, it reminded me of when students ask for a book that "covers everything".

Comment: @DKNguyen, oh, I see - wild and unsubstantiated guesswork, then, not taken from the requirements...some good fact-based engineering :-) :-)

Comment: “Good artists copy, great artists steal.” - Pablo Picasso

Comment: 1. Their training: in my personal experience I've learn't a lot of things while going through the process of becoming an engineer - but there are different kinds of engineers and schools/universities.  Some learnt better, others train better.  2. Experience. 3. Documentation such as datasheets, application notes. 4. Try demo boards. 5. Determine possible approaches, learn more if needed, seek help if needed, talk to FAE.  5. (Based on 1). Use their engineering skills and intellect they should have as engineers.  6. Innovate

Comment: Incidentally, I do like these questions where everyone knows it's off-topic but there's always a few who'd normally criticise the OP for asking then can't bear to not to pour out their life story anyway. Happens on so many questions. *This is off-topic for this site and no-one should answer. Except me, of course, obviously, I'm exempt. So...* OPs must get very mixed messages from this site :-)

Comment: @TonyM I recognized that it might be off-topic until interpreted the phrase "look for reliable circuit" as applying to using a simulator. I guess for the most part, if I hadn't seen this little shaft of light, I would also have voted to close. So, when you say "everyone", maybe not on this occasion.

Comment: "Re-use" is a smart and standardized strategy/methodology in design industry for lesser time-to-market and engineering cost; provided that the circuit being re-used is a fully verified entity.

Answer (score 5):

> *where do HW engineers \$\color{red}{\text{look for}}\$ reliable circuits that would work for
> the first time of prototype*

I've emphasized \$\color{red}{\text{look for}}\$ because I'm using it in a more general way than what the OP may have thought of.

So, I \$\color{red}{\text{look for}}\$ problems and solutions in my simulator....

To give the best chance possible to make a prototype work first time (maybe with a few value changes at worst) I use a simulation tool. I always use it and I always simulate then, when I'm happy, I don't bother with a bread-board prototype, I go straight to a 1st issue PCB.

This saves really quite a lot of time because you are forced head first into facing the problems of your design from the luxury of your desk. Do this first and your yield will improve. My estimation is this: -

- Per finished design (simple to complex average) I can save may 1.5 PCB iterations
- I don't need to bread-board anything
- The first prototype can usually be easily modified to fix things missed during the simulation phase so that a demonstrable and fairly stable working prototype can be assessed by customers etc..
- Many designs just "work first time" (maybe over 50% if I put a figure to it). My latest was a 10 kW Cuk converter that, guess what, worked first time. OK, there was some functionality left out that needed a few mods but, it journeyed to the customer's test house and passed first time.

More specifically, I never acquire components from flaky sources\$^1\$; I use proper dealerships selling recognized component brands and get a paper trail back to source. I want quality gear and that's the way to do it.

---

\$^1\$ - Flaky sources - peeBay, bang-bad, mali-express, shamazon etc..

Comment: Agree. If I find something online that "might work", I abhor the thought of throwing it into a circuit without subjecting it to thorough simulation. And god - have I identified a lot of flawed stuff out there... To the point, that I generally start right in spice instead of google.

Comment: oh man I really need to up my SPICE game.

Comment: oooh, I might just start colouring text now in my answers

Comment: Coloring text - way above my pay grade.  But to Anyd's point about prototyping/breadboarding - can't agree more.  For the last 25 or 30 years, we've gone directly to multi-layer PCBs, even for proof of concept.  At today's speeds, vector board, wirewrap, termipoint just won't cut it.  And some problems are layout related, which may not show up or else show up differently when you get the final implementation (PCB).  We almost always plan on at least 2 spins of a PCB, and for high risk or really new designs 3 spins.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Andy, when you design a circuit do you start by drawing your idea with pencil and paper (and maybe some hand calculations) or do you jump straight into a simulator and design your circuit in there from the get-go?

Comment: I go straight to the simulator after collecting all the design input information in a word like document. Then I solve parts in turn and reference them to each bullet point of the requirements. This then builds a sizeable document that fully demonstrates design intent.

Comment: @Andy aka - I would love to see an example to such document if at all possible

Comment: @Mike it's usually a word document that I put all the input requirements in. I can't give examples out because they are sensitive to customers (some extremely sensitive if you take my meaning).

Answer (score 5):

The very first thing I do is work out ***exactly*** what I want to achieve. If I do understand the broad strokes of the topic, but not sufficiently well-versed in the details yet, then I spend time studying the topic until I can sit down and perform the work "by hand." Even in the most complex cases, that is always possible to do. Keep in mind that the human mind and theory existed long and far before electronics did. You should be able to figure it out with gears and cogs or even with sand and rocks, if necessary. At least, in principle.

Once you understand the topic and your goals well enough, then it is just a matter of using imagination to work out additional ways to achieve similar results. With several different approaches towards a goal, you can make some trade-off decisions and you are left with a smaller pile of ideas -- perhaps only one or two.

If there are remaining knowable unknowns -- things that you need to resolve in more detail before proceeding, those are pulled to the front and experimental design takes place in order to resolve them. These are sub-projects designed to turn the knowable unknowns into knowable knowns.

It may be the case, at this point, that you decide it is impossible. The project is aborted, then. (Until something new arrives in mind, anyway.)

Assuming it still seems feasible, there will still be things you don't know you don't know. So you spend a little time trying to imagine anything left over that you may have missed. If something arises, rinse and repeat. Otherwise, move on and hope that unexpected unknowns can be identified and successfully overcome if and when they arrive.

At this point, I'm in a position to examine prior work. I know what to look for and I know at least much of what to make of it, when I see it. I then think about what I see.

This is about the point where I start considering making a choice about which of the remaining ideas, and which of the implementations I've already examined, are more likely to get where I need to go. And I'm in a much better position to make those choices, by now.

Then I select an approach and spend still more time on it, both in theory first and then sitting down to make a prototype, having already divided it into sections that can be separately tested, with a notebook that provides me with my theoretical expectations ***before*** I sit down to make and test anything, so that I know what to expect and within what boundaries.

This is a vital step -- developing the expectations portion of the notebook. The reason is that if the results of experimentation match, you have some confidence in the process followed. If there are residuals that are not well explained, either the process itself was flawed (go back and re-check work product) or some new effect that needs to be tracked down is uncovered and exposed (more experimentation ahead to bring whatever it is into the knowable sphere, if possible.)

I think you can see a process, there. And it does NOT involve, at least not initially, "searching the web." That said, most things have been solved before in some fashion. So there is a point, very important, where the literature is examined to see what's been done, earlier. (Or your own memory from earlier experience.)

I'll leave it at that, for now.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is a discrete electronic circuit or FPGA "circuits".

I do re-use my older stuff, but I generally try to stay clear of foreign stuff that is unproven and/or which *I* have not understood.

It is not always avoidable to use foreign IP especially for deeper FPGA functions which would take too long for me to rebuild/understand. But the more experience I gain over the years, it becomes more and more likely.

Why ? At the end of the day, you always suffer. For me it is very preferable to suffer from my own mistakes, such as [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/599348/why-does-the-comparator-burn-in-this-oscillator-circuit) prime recent example. That mistake was completely avoidable, if I had used a premade part instead of drawing my own symbols. But when contrasting this with the times that I might have used a wrong symbol while relying on premade parts, I would use my own stuff any day.